# Implement Asp.Net Ajax Controls in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax

I was reading [telerik](http://xblogs.kompas-xnet.si/post/Telerik-ASPNET-AJAX-Controls-in-MVC-project.aspx) post 
 About Telerik ASP.NET AJAX Controls in MVC project. According to them we can implement Telerik AJAX control in Asp.Net MVC. So my question is can we implement ASP.Net Ajax control in my Asp.Net MVC Project.
If Yes how could it should be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, but you must be aware of the limitations.  You can read more from their [documentation on Telerik.com](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/mvc-radcontrols-for-aspnet-mvc-overview.html); they have some documentation on this process.  I would recommend using the MVC helpers where possible.